# How to add custom product on catalog search collection?

Tags: magento, search, collections, catalog

Currently i am trying to add custom product on CatalogSearch product collection . Currently i am working on `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer`. I know that its core part but after working my code properly i manage with override `CatalogSearch_Model`.

Currently i am working on this method

```
 public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);

// my custom code start

$collection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array(1,2));

$collectiondata=$collection2->getData();

foreach($collectiondata as $customdata)
{
$collection->addItem($customdata);
}

        return $this;
    }
```

this code add my custom product to collection but issue start when when in search result no product found.Means if in search product found then it add my custom product otherwise not.

I want to know where i am making mistake ? or any step missing. Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the issue:

```
$collection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array(1,2));
foreach($collection2 as $customdata)
{
$collection->addItem($customdata);
}
```

$collection2->getData(); is give not  proper object for  $customdata.

$customdata is give  proper `object of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

Comment: will you please elaborate?

Comment: But when i am using $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection')->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array(1,2)); it gives also same result for me. @amit

Comment: @KeyurShah ,see u tomorrow.